# Is BaseGameUtils Still Needed for Leaderboards?

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-games, leaderboard, basegameutils

Every single tutorial and stackoverflow question seems to indicate that it is needed and should be downloaded at android-basic-samples here:
https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples

However, BaseGameUtils was removed from the android-basic-samples project that everyone links to.  Also the ReadMe for android-basic-samples describing running the samples doesn't mention the need for BaseGameUtils anywhere.

This question:
[Is BaseGameUtils still necessary? (Implementing Android leaderboards)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789642/is-basegameutils-still-necessary-implementing-android-leaderboards)
asks exactly what I would like to know, except it was asked before BaseGameUtils was removed from android-basic-samples, and its answer incorrectly claims BaseGameUtils is referenced in some linked Google documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards
The question also incorrectly says BaseGameUtils is mentioned by this:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart

Google offers no explanation that I can find as to why BaseGameUtils was removed from android-basic-samples.  So I ask:

Is BaseGameUtils still needed for leaderboards implementation?

Answer (score 1):

No, that library is no longer required due to some changes to the Google Play Game Services API. The current documentation is outdated.

Here you can find more information. You can download the example game they leave there. And that will serve as a reference to start with. [Get Started with Play Games Services for Android](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart)